# Handwritten mathematical operators Database

Tags: neural-network, dataset, deep-learning, mnist

I'm looking for handwritten mathematical operators Database like MNIST (the handwritten database for digits) to develop a new application using neural network.

For the moment, i found only one satisfactory source on Kaggle with 45x45 jpep images extracted from CROHME.

Are there any other (better) sources known of mathematical symbols ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this dataset [HAMEX](http://ivc.univ-nantes.fr/en/databases/HAMEX/), though it was also one of the datasets partially merged to form the dataset for CROHME.

You can find more information and other datasets [here](http://ivc.univ-nantes.fr/en/databases/INK_ME/).